# Broadcast if a bluetooth device is connecting/disconnecting?

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I want start a service, when a specific bluetoothdevice is connected and stop this service when it's disconnected.
Obviously I don't want to have a background service that is always checking if a BT device is connected, so I want to achieve this with a Receiver.

Is this actually possible? `android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED` is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510500/android-bluetooth-device-connected-broadcast), but apparently it didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
    <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED" />
    <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
</intent-filter>
```

These are the filters you have to add with your broadcast receiver.

`ACL_CONNECTED` signals when bluetooth is connected and `ACL_DISCONNECTED` signals bluetooth disconnection

For specific device you have to check intents/context in broadcast receiver

The two permission you have to add are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I thought ACL_CONNECTED would be only for Audio devices ^^

Comment: Just in case someone is using this code, ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED and ACL_DISCONNECTED are not called if the user turns off Bluetooth!

Comment: Yes it does not. it only gets called (according how I use it in my code) when data is going to transfer via bluetooth and when its stop transmitting but you have to use bluetooth code to check bluetooth is close or open

Comment: my problem is that this event is fired during connection with a device !! what sould i do ??

Comment: Please clearify your question and I would suggest post a separate question so that it can reach to many

Comment: permission android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN is not required. look at the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice