# How to set beep sound when mobile out of the range without button onclick event?

Tags: android

How to set beep sound when mobile out of the range without button onclick event?using Mediaplayer.when mobile out of the range it  continous send beep sound and in range it not beep.Please help me.I am new in android.

Comment: Out of the range! Range of what?

Comment: use BroadcastReceiver, there are plenty of examples

Comment: @user3528450 Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8006522/2176708).

Comment: when mobile is away from the Tag it give me some beepsound and when it near to Tag at that time beepsound is stop.

Answer (score 0):

You Have More than One Option For Example Handlers , Broadcastreceiver and a service.

For Handler

```
    Handler mediaHandler = new Handler();
       if(something)
      mediaHandler.postDelayed(MediaTimeTask, 5000);
   private Runnable MediaTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mPlay = MediaPlayer
                .create(FutureJobReminder.this, R.raw.breakalert);

        mPlay.setLooping(false);
        mPlay.start();
        mediaHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);

        if (somecondition to stop the alert ) {

            stopme();
        }

    }
};


    private void stopme() {
    try {
        mPlay.stop();
        mediaHandler.removeCallbacks(MediaTimeTask);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

SO here is  BroadcastReceiver

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver abcd = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     //dosomething
        Startalert();
     }
};



  public void Startalert( ) {

  MediaPlayer mplay;
  mplay = MediaPlayer.create(NewMessage.this, R.raw.alert);
   //R.raw.alert is a sound which is in raw folder 
  mplay.start();
  mPlay.setLooping(true);//this will hepl you you to call you sound again and again
  mPlay.stop();//stop alert sound
}
```

don't forget to  unregister the BroadcastReceiver and release media.

```
unregisterReceiver(abcd);
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: please help me.how to use handler for set beep sound.

Comment: Try to do it by your self it has no rocket science, and what i have give you (code snippets) is more than enough.