# Autorun application when phone connected to pc

Tags: android

Is there a way to open an application from dekstop pc (such as an autorun) when the Android device is connected to pc?

Say that I have been creating an Android Application, and then the application is installed in my Android device (phone / tablet). And I want to give this application a special authority that will let the device to run the app automatically when the device is connected to pc.

Actually, the command that will be run by this app is only a command to open a web browser.

My question is:

***How to give this application a special authority that will let the device to run the app automatically when the device is connected to pc?***

Can someone give me a lighten?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register broadcast receiver that will wait for example for battery change state broadcast (see this: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html). When such broadcast is received, determine if you are connected to PC and start proper activity.

I guess that you might need your application to work all time (have started sticky service) to make this work.

Comment: Very good idea, and I will try to explore it more, hope that I can figure it out easily. 

Now can you please give me more idea when I need to run this method by Bluetooth connection.Many thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006407/broadcast-if-a-bluetooth-device-is-connecting-disconnecting

Comment: @al_kasih_empatix There are many broadcasts that you may check for, in order to start your activity... such as `(USB) ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED External power has been connected to the device.` or even `UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED`, then again if you only need bluetooth, then [check the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html) for it, on its broadcasts `ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST`, `ACTION_FOUND`, etc..