# In android, How can I run a background service that in case of a specific bluetooth device connect it activates the microphone?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-service

I want to create an app that also when the application is not running (UI) it will say something (use the mic) when a specific bluetooth device is connected. so i was thinking to create some kind of a background service that waits for the device to connect (preferebly waiting and not check every some seconds).
I am new to android.
thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you'll have to register a receiver for bluetooth events and catch the event with a BroadcastReceiver. Have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510500/android-bluetooth-device-connected-broadcast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a broadcast receivers instead to listen to the bluetooth device connection event. You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)